# Ignore first two special characters, and grab everything after that

Tags: jquery, regex

The nature of problem i am in is like, as described below:

I have string like that `radiobutton1_2_3_4` or `imagelist_1_34_54`

what I want to do is to grab everything after 3rd underscore(_).

`id.substring(id.indexOf('_')` I tried to this but in my case it did not worked.

Regards

Comment: everything after 2nd or 3rd `_` can you give a sample of the desired output

Comment: i want to grab 4 and 54 in that case.

Comment: in case of imagelist_1_34_54
i want to store 54, 34, 1 in different variables for further processing like
var a = 54
var b =34
var c =1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always going to be the last underscore you could use `id.substring(id.lastIndexOf('_'))`, otherwise `id.split('_')[3]` should work.

```
var split = id.split('_');
var a = split[1], b = split[2], c = split[3];
```

That will store your three numbers in a,b,c

Comment: yeah i knoiw that can work but i need all these meaning 
imagelist_1_34_54
i want to store all that is after first underscore after second and after third. i can do that but +1, +3, +5 in that perticuler case but here these would change so i need another aprroach

Comment: So now you want to get everything after each underscore? Not just the third one?

Comment: if you can tell any after third than there is no problem with 2nd and first !